# Listview inside the scroll view in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I am trying to make this type of view

there 3 types of news latest,sport and old news which are having 3 listview the data is populating but i am unable to scroll it the list view or the complete scroll view is not scrolling i had trying it from the 1 week  please find the below code

[image: This type of layout]

I am able to the layout but it's not scrolling at all

First tab view

```
class First_Tab_Layout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    First_State fst_state() => new First_State();
    return fst_state();
  }
}

class First_State extends State<First_Tab_Layout> {
  List latest_news_list;
  List sports_news_list;
  List cinema_news_list;

  latestnews() async {
    var latest_news_url = common_url + 'getlatestPosts';
    print(latest_news_url);
    http.Response latest_newsresponse = await http.get(latest_news_url);
    var latest_news_response = json.decode(latest_newsresponse.body);
    setState(() {
      latest_news_list = latest_news_response['posts'];
    });
  }

  sportsnews() async {
    var sports_news_url = common_url + 'getsportsPosts';
    print(sports_news_url);
    http.Response sports_newsresponse = await http.get(sports_news_url);
    var sports_news_response = json.decode(sports_newsresponse.body);
    setState(() {
      sports_news_list = sports_news_response['posts'];
    });
  }

  cinemanews() async {
    var cinema_news_url = common_url + 'getcinemaPosts';
    print(cinema_news_url);
    http.Response cinema_newsresponse = await http.get(cinema_news_url);
    var cinema_news_response = json.decode(cinema_newsresponse.body);
    setState(() {
      cinema_news_list = cinema_news_response['posts'];
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    latestnews();
    sportsnews();
    cinemanews();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new Scaffold(
          body: new ListView(
        primary: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            child: new Text(
              'Latest News',
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 5.0),
            alignment: Alignment(-1.0, 0.0),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: new Divider(
              color: secondarycolor,
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0, left: 10.0),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: new ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: latest_news_list == null ? 0 : latest_news_list.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int indexpos) {
                return new GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        new MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => new News_Details(
                                  postid: latest_news_list[indexpos]['id'],
                                )));
                  },
                  child: new Card(
                    elevation: 4.0,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 5.0),
                    child: new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Container(
                          child: new Image.network(
                            latest_news_list[indexpos]['image'],
                            width: 150.0,
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                        ),
                        new Flexible(
                          child: new Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Container(
                                child: new Text(
                                    latest_news_list[indexpos]['title']),
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                              ),
                              new Container(
                                child: new Text(
                                  latest_news_list[indexpos]['content'],
                                  softWrap: true,
                                  maxLines: 4,
                                ),
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 5.0),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: new Text(
              'Sports News',
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 5.0),
            alignment: Alignment(-1.0, 0.0),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: new Divider(
              color: secondarycolor,
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0, left: 10.0),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: new ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: sports_news_list == null ? 0 : sports_news_list.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int indexpos) {
                return new GestureDetector(
                  child: new Card(
                    elevation: 4.0,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 5.0),
                    child: new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Container(
                          child: new Image.network(
                            sports_news_list[indexpos]['image'],
                            width: 150.0,
                            height: 75.0,
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                        ),
                        new Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Container(
                              child:
                                  new Text(sports_news_list[indexpos]['title']),
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                            ),
                            new Container(
                              child:
                                  new Text(sports_news_list[indexpos]['title']),
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 5.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: new Text(
              'Cinema News',
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 5.0),
            alignment: Alignment(-1.0, 0.0),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: new Divider(
              color: secondarycolor,
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0, left: 10.0),
          ),
          new Container(
            child: new ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: cinema_news_list == null ? 0 : cinema_news_list.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int indexpos) {
                return new GestureDetector(
                  child: new Card(
                    elevation: 4.0,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 5.0),
                    child: new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Container(
                          child: new Image.network(
                            cinema_news_list[indexpos]['image'],
                            width: 150.0,
                            height: 75.0,
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                        ),
                        new Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Container(
                              child: new Text(
                                  cinema_news_list[indexpos]['categorytitle']),
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                            ),
                            new Container(
                              child: new Text(
                                  cinema_news_list[indexpos]['categorytitle']),
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 5.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

This worked for me. Not sure whether this will work for you. Try once. I just added physics to inner `ListView`.

```
new Container(
            child: new ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: The physics things fixed my problem so it still works in version 1.9.1 of flutter as a fix

Comment: The shrinkwrap thing makes the listview expanded at once, and NeverScrollable thing makes the scrolling in it disabled making the whole page scroll.

But what if I want both to scroll in a way the listview is not expanded and the scroll events are claimed in an appropriate manner between both

Comment: this fix my problem, listview inside customscrollview inside tabbarview.. to scroll parent colapsing widget

Comment: still working today :) thank you very much

Comment: Works. Just make sure ListView.builder isn't inside Expandable.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 20.0),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                selectedAddressSection(),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 10, 0, 10),
                  child: Text("YOUR FAVOURITE PAYMENT METHODS",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          fontFamily: 'Novecento Book',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ),
                selectedPaymentMethod(),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 10, 0, 10),
                  child: Text("PAYMENT DETAILS",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          fontFamily: 'Novecento Book',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                      child: Text(
                        "Subtotal",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Novecento Book',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                      child: Text(
                        '\u{20B9}${2500.00}',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Novecento Book',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                      child: Text(
                        "Shipping",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Novecento Book',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                      child: Text(
                        'Free',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Novecento Book',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                Divider(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                  height: 10,
                  thickness: 0.5,
                  indent: 10,
                  endIndent: 10,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                      child: Text(
                        "Grand total",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Novecento Book',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                      child: Text(
                        '\u{20B9}${2500.00}',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                            fontFamily: 'Novecento Book',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Divider(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                  height: 20,
                  thickness: 0.5,
                  indent: 10,
                  endIndent: 10,
                ),
                // standardDelivery(),
                //priceSection()
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}