# Put multiple ListViews with in a column in Flutterflow

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

I am developing an app in the Flutterflow no-code app development tool.
I have a column where I want to put two ListViews, like below

**Column**

- ListView#1
- ListView#2

I have already added ListView#1 and am getting an error when I try to add ListView#2 to the column. The error message is:

> A Column cannot be set to Scrollable when a child is set to Expanded

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listview inside the scroll view in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266307/listview-inside-the-scroll-view-in-flutter)

Comment: flag shrink wrap true

Answer (score 0):

For both use inside your `ListView` use the below properties

```
physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
shrinkWrap: true,
```

[You can also follow this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kZ0RiYYR2E)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Expanded` widget

```
Column:
    Expanded:
        child: ListView#1
    Expanded:
        child: ListView#2
```

What is the [difference between the `Expanded` widget and the `Flexible` widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645944/flutter-expanded-vs-flexible)